# psql: illegal option -- user=postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-desktop

I have launched a postgres docker container using:

```
docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=x -p 5432:5432 
registry.gitlab.com/dalibo/postgresql_anonymizer
```

and then trying to connect it using:

```
set PGPASSWORD=x
psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --user=postgres
```

But,when i am trying it to connect it using the above commands on the Windows cmd, it is throwing error:

```
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker>psql --host=localhost --port=5432 --user=postgres
psql: illegal option -- user=postgres
Try "psql --help" for more information.
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the option `--username=USERNAME` as described by `psql --help` and [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is resolved now. Really appreciated.